# How to access SQL server via data service in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, and I need help to connect my Angular 2 application to Sql Server.

I also have a WCFDataService running on my localhost. I'm using this to access it:

```
private _productUrl = 'localhost:23922/WcfDataService.svc/Portfolios';
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
               .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
               .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
               .catch(this.handleError);
}
getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
    return this.getProducts()
               .map((products: IProduct[]) => products.find(p => p.pId === id));
}
```

Comment: You should write a web service.

Comment: What kind of data service did you create? In Angular you can just make HTTP requests or use WebSocket to communicate to a webserver. Angular doesn't communicate with an SQL server directly (as any browser application). The web server you communicate to needs to translate the HTTP requests to SQL commands to the SQL server.

Comment: its a WCFDataService running on my localhost. Im using this to access it private _productUrl = 'localhost:23922/WcfDataService.svc/Portfolios'; getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getProduct(id: number): Observable<IProduct> {
        return this.getProducts()
            .map((products: IProduct[]) => products.find(p => p.pId === id));
    }